# Real world well formulated examples of non linear optimization problems

Tags: optimization, examples-counterexamples

I'm trying to find around the web some real world examples of non linear optimization problems. I currently need examples of:

- Non restringed optimziation ( $\max$/$\min$ $f(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or with $x_{i}>0$)
- Lineary restringed optimization
- Quadratic optimization
- Convex optimization
- Separable optimization
- Non-convex optimization
- Geometric optimization
- Fraccional optimization
- complementary optimizacion

Also, any real-world example of optimization problem would be very much apreciated.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Is for the introduction of a work, yeah.

Comment: So you want us to just do your research for you?

Comment: No, I just wanted to know where can i search. First answer is being  quite helpfull :)

Comment: I've been doing some "hobby work" on optimization, and I have struggled to find anything to optimize apart from long lists of pathological "test functions", so it is a good question from my POV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at some of the case studies at http://www.neos-guide.org/
or browse the Optimization Online archive at http://www.optimization-online.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can find a wealth of examples in the book [Convex Optimization](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) by Boyd and Vandenberghe.